# Django Allauth - Applying Signup Function on Custom Signup HTML file

Tags: python, django-allauth

I'm new to django and I'm trying to make Signup Function with Django allauth library.
But it's difficult to me for making Signup funcion to be worked on my Custom HTML file so needs your help.

Originally, Django allauth Signup template is like this.

**django-allauth/allauth/templates/account/signup.html**

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>
```

and my new customed HTML file is like this.

**mysite/templates/account/signup.html**

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action= "{% url 'account_signup' %}" >
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}

  <div class="signup_body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="home_list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div>name</div>
              <div class="textinput">
                  <input type="text" id="signup_name" placeholder="please name" v-model="name">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="home_list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div>email</div>
              <div class="textinput">
                  <input type="email" id="signup_email" placeholder="please email" v-model="email">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="home_list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div>password</div>
              <div class="textinput">
                  <input type="password" id="signup_password" placeholder="password" v-model="password">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="home_list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div>double check password</div>
              <div class="textinput">
                  <input type="password" id="signup_repassword" placeholder="type again" v-model="passwordAgain">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type = "submit">
        <div class="home_list_btn">
            <div class="grobal_btn">
                <h4 class="grobal_btn_primary grobal_btn_round">Complete</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and I don't know how to work with `form' tag in HTML for sending data into DB and moving user into next custom page.

I was trying input next page info into `action` parameter in form tag, and it works, but data wasn't submitted and not saved.

How to set this HTML page to sending user signup data into DB/Server and moving user into next page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace:

```
<input type="email" id="signup_email" placeholder="please email" v-model="email">
```

by:

```
<input type="email" id="signup_email" placeholder="please email" name="email">
```

or simply just :

```
{{ form.email }}
```

the reason is that [Signup form](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/forms.py#L364) which provided by django-allauth contains such fields: `email, username, password1, password2` so you have to strict with those name to setup your html form.

Just FYI, Django provide Django Form to allow you to handle data between client side and server side. It allows you to validate input data, `ModelForm` also allow you to save the data into your database via Django Model.